# show that the set of irrational numbers fails to be closed

Tags: real-analysis

The definition used here of closed is that: a sequence is closed if $\{a_n\}$ is in the set $S$ and $\{a_n\}$ converges to $a$, then $a$ is in $S$. So I have shown in a previous problem that every number is the limit of a sequence of irrational numbers. So can we say that if $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence of irrational numbers and lives in the irrationals, then its limit a does not live in the irrationals because a is a natural number?

Answer (score 4):

Notice  that ${1\over 2^n\sqrt{2}}$ is irrational for all $n$ and that it converges to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you already know, all real numbers are limits of irrationals. So select the rational (and therefore real) number $q$, let $I$ be the set of irrational numbers and let $a_n$ be a sequence of irrationals converging to $q$. Since $\{a_n\}\subseteq I$ is a sequence in $I$, with a limit outside of $I$, $I$ is not closed by definition.

Answer (score 0):

More generally,
for any dense set of reals
(irrationals, rationals,
dyadic rationals,
...)
*every* real
is in its closure.